# Use Select change event on dropkick

Tags: jquery, jquery-dropkick

I recently update the jquery version on my website due to an update of the CMS spip, and in consequence i had to also update the dropkick.js.

I would like to get a form submit on a select change.
Before the update i used this code who worked fine:

```
$('.x_select').dropkick({
    change:function(value,label) {
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
     }
});
```

But whith the new version of dropkick http://dropkickjs.com/api.html
it doesnt work anymore, and i dont know what i have to modify.. Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form as shown below:

```
$('.x_select').dropkick({
    change:function(value,label) {
      $(this.form).submit();//changed here
     }
});
```